# what is db_load?

Tags: ftp, database, vsftpd

I saw this line on [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd). What is db_load? **Is that kind of database like mySQL and ORACLE **?

```
# db_load -T -t hash -f vusers.txt vsftpd-virtual-user.db
```

Comment: Hello visitor, I bet you are here because you Googled after reading "may require the **db_util** package to be installed first" on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd Well, it should have been a dash not underscore. `apt-cache search db-util`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `db_load` utility is provided by the [db-util](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/db-util) package.

The complete man page for this command is available [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man1/db_load.1.html).